# Possible error in a STEP Paper: Matrix Group (STEP 1991 P2 Q9)

Tags: matrices, group-theory, solution-verification

I have been doing some STEP papers and I think I found a mistake on one of the papers. The paper is from 1991 (STEP 2) and the question (Q9) goes as follows:

Let $G$ be the set of all matrices of the form
$
\
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   0 & c \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\
$ where a,b and c are integers modulo $5$, $a\neq0\neq b$. Show that $G$ forms a group under matrix multiplication (which may be assumed to be associative).

I've proven that the identity exists and is unique, however, I can't prove that the inverses are going to exist within G and ,moreover, that G is closed. Here are my arguments

**Inverses**

Suppose there exists $A$ such that 
$A \times
\
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   0 & c \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\
$
$=
\
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\
$
. It follows that 
$A=
\
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   0 & c \\
  \end{array} } \right]^{-1}
\
$
$=\frac{1}{ac}
\
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   c & -b \\
   0 & a \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\
$. The issues that arise are that $\frac{c}{ac}$ is not nesseraly an intiger for intiger c and similarly $\frac{a}{ac}$ is also not necceserally an intiger. Thus for $a\neq 1\neq c$  the inverses are not a member of $G$.

**Closure**

Let 
$
\
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   0 & c \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\
$
and 
$
\
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   d & e \\
   0 & f \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\
$
be members of $G$. In doing matrix multiplication we get
$
\
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   0 & c \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\
\times
\
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   d & e \\
   0 & f \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\
=
\
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   ad & ae+bf \\
   0 & cf \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\
$

We see that if $d$ is a multiple of $5$ then $ad\equiv0 \mod{5}$. However, if the new matrix is formed $ad$ must obey $ad \neq 0$ which it obviously doesn't. Thus it is not closed.

Can someone have a look at my arguments and let me know what I have done wrong or if I am right ?

Here is the link to the full paper:

https://pastpapercache.blob.core.windows.net/ppppapers/step/STEP%20II%201991.pdf

Thanks in advance

Comment: The integers modulo $5$ form a field: each nonzero element has a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: Hi @AnginaSeng thanks for the response. I am yet to cover fields in terms of number and group theory so I am not too sure what you mean by that. Also, do you know why is my argument wrong?

Comment: If $a \neq 0 \mod 5$ then we can find $b \mod 5$ such that $ab=1 \mod 5$. This follows from Bezout's lemma which is good to have in your toolbox. Best of luck with your application!

Comment: Can **you** give an **example** of an element of $G$ lacking an inverse?

Comment: @Kanye West: The exam problem is not incorrect. Note that the exam has $a\ne 0$ and $c\ne 0$, so you have a typo in your statement of the problem. Also, all matrix entries can be expressed as elements of the set $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ with all operations done mod $5$.

Comment: Also, for the inverse you should not divide the way you do; you should use the multiplicative inverse operation inherited from the fact that integers mod 5 form a field as noted by Angina.

Comment: @E-A By multiplicable inverse do you mean for example $\frac{1}{3}=1 \mod{3}$? And if yes, doesn't that mean that the inverse is not unique as $1\mod{3}= 1 \mod{5} $or$ 4\mod{5}$? If that is not what you meant could you clarify as what you meant by multiplicative inverse? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AnginaSeng For $
\
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 2 \\
   0 & 3 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\
$ I haven't been able to find an unique inverse. Atleast the way I interepreted diving by 1/3. (I wrote my interpretation in my comment to E-A and in my comment to the answer given by Wrench). Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Consider $\pmatrix{1&1\\0&2}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When working with cogruences, we think of "division" as "multiplying by the multiplicative inverse". Since both $a\not=0$ and $c\not=0$, then $\frac{1}{ac}$ is well-defined and we have existence of inverses. Closure is also satisfied since $a,c,d,f\not=0$. (Note: G is not commutative).

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I have a few questions. Could you elaborate on why $\frac{1}{ac}$ is well defined as I am inexperienced in combining discrete and linear algebra? Also, it is not given that $a,c,d,f \neq 0$, is it implied by the question saying they are intigers thus discounting 0? Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what quasi wrote the exam has  $a\not=0$ and $c\not=0$ so $\frac{1}{ab}$ is well-defined since it is not 0. Similarly as $a\not=0$ and $c\not=0$ by assumption if we introduce a second matrix from G as you've done for closure, then $d,f\not=0$ as well.

Comment: You are right! Just a quick question. If I have for example an element of the matrix being $\frac{1}{3}$ would that translate to $1 \mod{3}$ which translates to $1 \mod {5}$ or $4 \mod{5}$ and moreover if that logic is correct doesn't that imply that the inverse is not unique? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this case if you wanted to find the inverse of 3 mod 5, you would write $3^{-1}=2 mod 5$ since $3(2)=6=1mod5$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{3}$ does not mean 1 mod 3.  The question says the values are mod 5, that doesn't change just because you have a fraction.  $\frac{1}{3}$ mod 5 means the inverse of 3 mod 5.

Comment: Thanks @Ted for clarifying it, now it all makes sense.